# Тире или запятая и тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Интересно оформление предложений двух видов:

1. Первая часть БСП включает однородный ряд членов, а далее следует тире:

   "В-третьих, у него непременно где-нибудь на физиономии, на руке, на шее есть болячки, - это его задело машиной и рану растравил свинец" (М. Горький).
2. После однородных придаточных ставится тире:

   "Что горько мне, что тяжко было и что внушало прибыль сил, с чем жизнь справляться торопила, –  я всё сюда и заносил" (Твардовский).

Вопрос: правильно поставить тире или запятую и тире? Может быть, считать запятую и тире единым знаком? Дело в том, что одно тире плохо смотрится, да и  запятая и тире часто встречается в текстах.

У Лопатина запятой нет: "Где я буду этот учебный год, переведусь ли куда — ведь обо всём этом надо думать!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vera, это бесконечный вопрос. Именно в отношении встречи тире и запятой. Я несколько раз пытался навести хоть какую-то систему (даже тут, на этом ресурсе, если покопаться можно найти), но безуспешно. Вся беда в том, что нет единого понимания, что делать, когда по одним мотивам нужно тире с запятой, а по другим - просто тире, которое поглощает запятую.

Для начала. Единым знаком считать тут никак нельзя. Под "единым знаком" понимается сочетание тире и запятой, когда для этого есть единый мотив. 
Единственный такой мотив в правилах обозначен как сложноподчиненное со следующими особенностями:

> Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении
>            Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении ставятся в качестве единого знака:
>                 1) перед главным предложением, которому предшествует ряд однородных придаточных, если подчеркивается распадение сложного целого
>   на две части, например: Кто виноват из них, кто прав, – судить не нам
>   (Крылов); Делал ли что-нибудь для этого Штольц, что делал и как делал,
>   – мы этого не знаем (Добролюбов);
>                 2) перед словом, которое повторяется для того, чтобы связать с ним новое предложение (чаще придаточное) или дальнейшую
>   часть того же предложения, например: Могло ли не отразиться в
>   литературе это новое общественное движение, – в литературе, которая
>   всегда бывает выражением общества! (Белинский); Теперь же, судебным
>   следователем, Иван Ильич чувствовал, что все без исключения, самые
>   важные, самодовольные люди, – все у него в руках (Л. Толстой);
>                 3) в п е р и о д е (значительном по объему предложении, чаще всего сложноподчиненном, которое делится паузой на две части – п
>   о в ы ш е н и е и п о н и ж е н и е) между его частями, например: В
>   тот час, когда уж, кажется, и сил не было дышать, когда солнце,
>   раскалив Москву, в сухом тумане валилось куда-то за Садовое кольцо, –
>   никто не пришёл под липы, никто не сел на скамейку, пуста была аллея
>   (Булгаков).
>            Внутри частей периода, если они значительно распространены, ставится точка с запятой.
>            В других случаях сочетания запятой и тире каждый из этих знаков ставится на своем основании, например: Пушкин, величайший наш
>   поэт, – основоположник русского литературного языка (запятая закрывает
>   обособленное приложение, тире ставится в месте пропуска связки).
>
> Справочник по правописанию и стилистике. — М.: Комплект. Д. Э.
>   Розенталь. 1997.
>   Цитирую отсюда.
>   http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/114/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8

Везде - только обычные ССП с союзами (союзными словами).
Я не вижу в ваших примерах ни одного из этих трех случаев, может быть, я ошибаюсь, тогда объясните, где.

Эта ситуация приоритетнее всех остальных, если есть такой мотив, то ни о чем больше думать не надо.

А вот когда тире и запятая ставятся по разным мотивам - это уже весьма дискуссионно. По большей части в такой ситуации не должно поглощать запятую. Но тоже не всегда. Надо долго и нудно разбираться - и не всегда ответ однозначно вытекает из имеющихся правил; т.е. имеет места элементарная лакуна в пунктуации. Здесь и сейчас не буду примеры приводить и разбираться, как нибудь в другой раз, прямого отношения к вашим примерам это не имеет.

По примерам.

Единственная трудность - у Горького. С остальными все ясно.

*"В-третьих, у него непременно где-нибудь на физиономии, на руке, на шее есть болячки, - это его задело машиной и рану растравил свинец"*.
Одно могу сказать сразу: проверять пунктуацию по Горькому занятие бесперспективное. У него в каждой строчке - авторский подход. К тому же основные правила по этой части до 56 г. еще не были никак кодифицированы.

По современным понятиям, здесь запятая, на мой взгляд, факультативна.
Но возможна, посеольку ставится не только по мотивам разделения составляющих БСП (для этой цели тут достаточно тире, которое заменяет запятую), но надо как-то зрительно закрыть часть, относящуюся к "в-третьих" - иначе получится, что это его" в-третьих" задело машиной.

*Кстати, еще надо крепко подумать над квалификацией этого предложения как БСП. Здесь какая необыная роль у слова "это". Без самого этого слова, предложение вполне смотрелось бы, имхо, и без запятой. Не буду сечас заниматься новаторством, просто мысли вслух.

*Что горько мне, что тяжко было и что внушало прибыль сил, с чем жизнь справляться торопила, – я всё сюда и заносил".

Все правильно. Запятая перед тире закрывать предшествующее подчиненное, а то что таких придаточных два и как они между собой и с главным сооьносятся, - это уже вопрос сюда не относящийся. Придаточное закрывается запятой = это и есть самостоятельный и самодостаточный мотив для постановки, последующее тире её не может поглотить.

*"Где я буду этот учебный год, переведусь ли куда — ведь обо всём этом надо думать!"*

А здесь нет мотива для запятой. Как нет и придаточного в левой части. Здесь ситуация больше похожа на "горьковскую", но там-то для этой запятой пришлось искать натянутые аргументы - по большей части просто для устранения "иначе плохо смотрится". А тут-то запятая зачем? Тире достаточно даже зрительно.

Извините, может, немного путано. Что-то трудно мне стали даваться длинные тексты... Если не понятно, я на свежую голову перечитаю - поправлю.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, правда, вопросов у меня стало еще больше, а понимания меньше. Тема смутная, противоречивая, плохо проработанная. Думаю, что мы имеем 4 варианта: 1) независимая мотивация, ставятся запятая и тире ; 2) независимая мотивация, но тире поглощается запятой; 3) мотивированная запятая, тире добавляется; 4) мотивированное тире, запятая добавляется.  И еще две неясности: 1) что мы вообще считаем единым знаком 2) когда решение авторское, а когда обязательное.  Пока всё это не будет четко определено, вопросы будут постоянно возникать, поэтому это тема для хорошего исследования.

Comment: А я не сомневался, что вопросов будет больше... Я вам на них не отвечу. Мутная тема... Тем более, что вон еще slava1947 у Лопатина еашел неведомое ранее миру правило. Формулировка позволяет думать, что оно Лопатиным и сформулировано в таком виде. .

Comment: "Думаю, что мы имеем 4 варианта" Пункт 2)  возможен тогда и только тогда, когда когда запятая авторская. Т.е. реально его вообще не надо рассматривать. Утверждение типа "Автор зоткл поставить запятую вопреки правилам, но отказался от этой затеи, поскольку есть тире" - это не для здоровыхумов . Далее 3 и 4) - это один вариант. А еще один - тире с запятой как единый знак, который слава раскопал у Лопатина.

Comment: Единый знак - случай, когда согласно четко прописанным правилам тире с запятой ставятся по единым  мотивам. Я три случая приводил. Лопатин добавил четвертый. Вы это примите как данность. Иначе разбираться бесполезно. Единый знак - это например, многоточие. Не три точки, а именно многоточие, ставящаяся по одному основанию.  Или "?!", "!!!", "???". В некоторомы смысле кавычки при прямой речи вместе с двоеточием и тире - они тоже ставятся по единым причинам. Вот собственно все. И про прямую речь - это я только для понимания, реально никто к "единому знаку" не относит, дабы совсем все не запутать

Comment: Да, еще раз убеждаюсь, что над темой надо работать. Например,  надо собрать практический материал по классическим произведениям, проанализировать, обобщить,  точно также проработать теорию,  ее обоснованность и мотивированность . - словом, то задача для будущего. Сейчас вряд ли  такая постановка вопроса найдет понимание, удобнее составлять правила, особо не напрягаясь по поводу их содержания.

Answer (score 1):

> "В-третьих, у него непременно где-нибудь на физиономии, на руке, на
>   шее есть болячки, - это его задело машиной и рану растравил свинец"
>   (М. Горький).
>
> …Вопрос: правильно поставить тире или запятую и тире?

Я бы поставил *запятую и тире* (если бы не было вводного "в третьих", может быть и ограничился бы одним тире), хоть этот знак и *утрачивает в настоящее время свою активность.*

См.  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135 :

> **§ 130**… *Примечание 1.* В бессоюзном сложном предложении **может ставиться запятая и тире как единый знак**, особенно при значении
>   присоединения во второй части предложения (знак этот в настоящее время
>   утрачивает свою активность)...

===============

> "Что горько мне, что тяжко было и что внушало прибыль сил, с чем жизнь
>   справляться торопила, – я всё сюда и заносил" (Твардовский).
>
> Вопрос: правильно поставить тире или запятую и тире?

См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134 :

> **§ 126.** В сложноподчиненном предложении ставится **запятая и тире**, если предложение построено в виде периода…
>
> ***Что*** горько мне, **что** тяжко было и **что** внушало прибыль сил, **с чем** жизнь справляться торопила, — я **всё** сюда и заносил (Тв.).

Comment: "*§ 130… Примечание 1. В бессоюзном сложном предложении*" - ой, что-то перемудрил Лопатин... Под эту формуоирорвку подпадает вообще любое БСП. Но хорошо хоть  только "может" и "утрачивает активнеость". Похоже, он тоже объяснить иначе не мог подобные конструкции, правилами нигде более не описанные.  Вот насчет Твардовского - это интресно. А разве закрыть придаточное - этого недостаточно? Зачем такие сложности с периодом?

Comment: slava, спасибо за ответ,  свое общее мнение я высказываю в верхнем комментарии.

Comment: Что такое "верхний комментарий"? Здесь нет верхнего и нижнего иначе как одном ответе. остальное - определяется личными настройками порядка сортировки.