# Пунктуация в приведенном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите разобраться со знаками препинания в предложении:

> Во всех концах древнего мира — оставляя здесь в стороне новый, — от Рима до Вавилона — можем мы указать ...[продолжение]

Если я не ошибаюсь, то *от Рима до Вавилона* выделяется с помощью тире, т.к. эта часть предложения объясняет сказанное ранее и имеет достаточную самостоятельность.

Больше всего меня сбивает выделение *оставляя здесь в стороне новый*. Я как-то могу понять аналогичными соображениями использование двух тире, но после слова *новый* также стоит запятая. Это единый знак **запятая и тире** или же они имеют отдельную причину? Подскажите правило, к которому стоит обратиться, для понимания подобной пунктуации.

Comment: Если в двух словах: все на совести автора, в данном случае переводчика. В русской традиции подобного стіка двух пар тире быть не должно, хотя в явном виде это и не оговаривается. Если найду оригинал (а Ницше читать, плохо зная немецкий - сами понимаете какое удовольствие), посмотрю, откуда ноги растут. И с запятой тоже. Тогда и отвечу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот немецкий оригинал.

> Aus allen Enden der alten Welt—um die neuere hier bei Seite zu
>   lassen—von Rom bis Babylon können wir die Existenz dionysischer Feste
>   nachweisen, deren Typus sich, besten Falls, zu dem Typus der
>   griechischen verhält, wie der bärtige bocksbeinige Satyr zu Dionysus
>   selbst.

http://www.thenietzschechannel.com/works-pub/bt/bt-1872g.htm

Во-первых, никакого выделения "от Рима до Вавилона" нет и в помине, во-вторых, фраза не слишком сложная, чтобы изобретать какие-то особенные приемы пунктуации. 
Таким образом, остается только оценить пунктуацию переводчика, явным образом  - авторскую. Честно говоря, я её до конца не понимаю.

В отношении тире и запятой как единого знака могу сказать только, что вопрос до конца не прояснен даже в теории, чтобы далеко не ходить - смотрите, например, [Тире или запятая и тире?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416024).

Видимо, переводчик начал с того, что захотел (вопреки оригиналу) как-то обособить, выделить часть "от Рима до Вавилона". Мое знание немецкого не позволяет судить, насколько это оправдано, но допустим. 
В результате получился стык двух пар тире, что само по себе уже вызывает вопросы. 
Но этого мало, появляется очевидная двусмысленность, ведь при таком построении фразы "от Рима до Вавилона" должно относиться к предыдущему ("мир новый от Рима до Вавилона), что явно противоречит смыслу. Вероятно, чтобы как-то выпутаться из этой ситуации переводчик (или редактор?) влепил еще и запятую, отделив тем самым два уточнения, оформленные в виде двух пар тире, друг от друга. Теперь Рим и Вавилон хотя бы зрительно не относятся к "новому миру". 
Конечно, все это домыслы, но реальных мотивов для запятой я там не вижу. При высказанной же версии запятая, естественно, должна считаться отдельным знаком, ибо мотив для неё иной, чем для тире.

Но повторюсь. Все сложности от того, что переводчик нарушил старое, негласное, но очень действенное правило: Двух тире в одном предложении не должно быть. Особенно парных и тем более - встык.